# How a subclass which extends a superclass calls the builder of parent class

Tags: java

I have a parent class like

```
 class A{

    //Constructors only called by builder.

 public static class builder{
   //builder code.
   }
 }

 Class B Extends ClassA{
    //constrctor

 }
```

Now if i do in my test

```
 final classA dempClassA = new ClassB("parameters here");
```

how can i call the builder now..?

Sorry guys the builder is a class...My mistake.

Comment: Are you asking about the builder class knowing about the subclass? If so, bad design: classes should not reference their subclasses. Consider moving the builder class into its own top-level class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well what you're trying to say, you have the following situation:

```
public class ClassA {

    // Constructors only called by builder.

    public static class Builder {
        // builder code.
        public static void hello() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }

        public void hello1() {
            System.out.println("Hello1");
        }
    }
}
```

And you access it this way:

```
class ClassB extends ClassA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassA.Builder.hello();
        ClassA.Builder builder = new Builder();
        builder.hello1();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call that method from outside the `A` class then it shouldn't be private.

If you just want it to be part of the `B` creation process then you should do something like this:

```
class B extends A {

  public B() {
    super(); // invokes A's constructor
  }
}

class A {
  public A(){
    // use builder() here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `builder` (is that a class btw? or is the return type missing?) is static, you'd call it like `A.builder()`. And for it to be visible, you shouldn't make it private :)

Edit: since it is a class, you have several possibilities:

- if you need a new instance call `new A.builder(...)`
- if builder provides static methods (in which case the question would be why this is a class) call `A.builder.someStaticMethod(...)`

Comment: sorry it's a class.I am trying to implement the builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Make ClassA's `builder` method `protected` (rather than `private`), so they're visible to ClassB, then use an anonymous class to call it, like this:

```
ClassA tempClassA = new ClassB("parameters here") {
    {  
       // This block is called during construction
       builder(); 
    }
};
```

Comment: I cannot think a real world scenario where I actually want to use something like this

Comment: Really? I do it all the time. Especially when populating maps with static values - I call put() from within an anonymous instance block to populate it during construction.

Comment: Yeah, the map thing is indeed useful (sometimes) but I never thought of using this stuff with my code... I guess it's a matter of taste anyway

Comment: I would only normally use this kind of code (in answer) for test code, which is what this question was about. IMHO in testing code you can do pretty much whatever you like as long as the real code is clean